# How can this click() work from inside content script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making an extension that clicks the submit button on a site after the captcha has been solved. I got the captcha value using the aria-checked attribute, however when it is time to click I receive the following error: " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined".

When i submit this code into the console it works:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].click();
```

When i put the code above directly inside the content script or directly inside a function and then call it, it clicks too! The problem arises when i try to click(); using a conditional

```js
setInterval(function checker() {
  if (document.getElementById("recaptcha-anchor")) {
    checado = document.getElementById("recaptcha-anchor").getAttribute('aria-checked');

    if (checado !== "false") {
      document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0].click();
    } else {

      console.log("not fire");
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried declaring `document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0]` completely outside of this function and then only calling `.click()` within it? For example, outside of this `setInterval` function, could you try `var submitButton = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0]`, and then within the conditional, `if (checado !== "false") {submitButton.click()}`

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for answering, I tried that but unfortunetly got the same error, "cannot read property click of undefined"

Comment: your answer makes sense  but javascript is being weird, the error still happens in the click() part tho, the declaration goes through fine

Comment: @sergioagustotech Huh, that's interesting...if the declaration is going through just fine, I wonder why when `click()` is called, it's considered undefined. Maybe let's see what happens if you `console.log(submitButton)` directly after following the variable declaration?

Comment: i tought that too, it prints 'undefined'. but if directly underneath i write 'document.getElementByClassName("button")[0].click();' . It clicks the submit button and the page reloads

Comment: This is tricky. Could you perhaps post the actual entire button element that you're trying to click? `<button class="so-and-so" id="so-and-so">` Maybe we're accessing it incorrectly.

Comment: sure `<button name="button" type="submit" value="keep" class="button">Play more
<small>
& Keep Watching
</small>
</button>`

Comment: You need to clear the interval after you clicked it - maybe your code actually clicks it but then the buttons gets removed and the code fails in the next run.

Comment: thank you for your answer but that can't be the case, if my code clicked it at least once i wouldn't receive an error. when it gets to the click() part it stops, so even if i put clearinterval() after, that line of code would never execute

Comment: It is very weird having the same code but if it is inside a conditional it is 'undefied'

Comment: guys upvote if you couldnt figure it out please